# How to fixed error: The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sdk

I'm design software in VS2008,
But when I'm coppy to another computer without install VS2008.
It throw a error

> **The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.**

I'm finding in the internet, some people show me install Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package 
I was install, but my application's Such errors are still.

When I install VS2008, it worked true.
- How to run this application without install VS2008

I think new computer's missing Microsoft SDK v6.0a,
- How to install Microsoft SDK v6.0a without install VS2008 ?

Thank !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you built your program in debug mode? That will cause a problem since the CRT (C Run-Time Libraries) in the redistributable package is built in release mode. That also explains why your program works again when you install Visual Studio on the other computer, since it includes debug builds of CRT.

Solution: build your application in release mode.

Comment: If your question was answered, please accept my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

(Not particularly directed at the OP - more for people googling the message as I was initially)

Have a look in the Windows Error logs (`eventvwr.exe`). A malformed `.exe.config` and other such snafus can also [confusingly] trigger the same headline message.

Comment: A malformed config file is what caused this error for me.